# Genotypes in diploid/haploid cells under mitotic/meotic cell divisions

Tags: genetics, population-genetics

I am new to genetics , and am stuck with the following question at hand:

> If $2$ cells with genotypes $(A/a)$ and $(A/a,B/b)$ undergo mitotic and meotic cell divisions respectively, what will be the  genotypes/gene compositions in the resultant diploid and haploid cells with respect to the above mentioned alleles?

Can someone help me how to proceed?

Comment: can you give a little more information - like what you think the answer might be? Is this a homework question?

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh Not homework in the true sense. It is actually a question in one of the previous year's question paper (so I doubted to give the self study tag ) that I couldn't solve and sadly neither is my professor available , nor are my friends getting anywhere.

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/doesnt-meiosis-form-two-pairs-of-similar-cells-and-two-pairs-of-opposite-cells

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though broad, here I provide a summary in graphical way.

### Mitosis:

[image: Mitosis] .

---

MEIOSIS: 2 successive steps : Meiosis-1 and meiosis-2

### Meiosis-1

[image: Meiosis 1]

---

### Meiosis-2

[image: meiosis-2]

---

So lets see what happens with cells given at question.

**1. Cell with genotype Aa**

(monohybrid or one-point cross-experiments; that means we are looking to gene-pair at 1 loci; not looking to any other genes):

**1. A.  Mitosis:**

Possible genotypes of their offsprings: All Aa.

**1. B. Meiosis:**

gametes will show 2-possibilities ; **A, a**.

---

**2. Cell with genotype AaBb**

(dihybrid or 2-point cross-experiments; that means we are looking on genes of 2 loci; not to any other cells):

**2.A. Mitosis:**

all offsprings **AaBb**.

**2.B. Meiosis:**

If given condition says the loci for A (or a) and B (or b) are on same chromosome (linked genes) and **no** crossing-over is there;

then We will get only 2 types of gamete **AB** and **ab**.

If crossing over(s) take place between the 2 loci; then we'll get 4 types of gamete **AB, Ab, aB, ab**; but their ocurring frequency will deviate from Mendel's independent assortment.

If the 2 loci are not-linked; i.e. they are located in distinct chromosome; then also we'll get 4 types of gametes **AB, Ab, aB, ab**; but they will follow Mendel's independent assortment pattern.

> Reference:
>
> 1. Concepts of Genetics, 8th Edition (EBook) By William Klug, Michael Cummings, Charlotte Spencer / Pearson; chapter 2 (mitosis and meiosis)
> 2. The science of Genetics, 6th edition, by George Burns and Paul Bottino, Macmillan.
> 3. Genetics/ P.K. Gupta/ Rastogi Publication Meerut

Comment: That was a wonderful explaination. Can you please (if possible) give me the source where genetics is so wonderfully expalined in detail?

Comment: @Qwerty I did it completely from memory and it is based on many days of classes and many books. Ok I'll look back to my books and will add some relevant reference.

Comment: @Qwerty I've added them

Comment: For your purpose you could also visit a book by Robert *Tamarin*, and for chromosome aberrations, there is an excellent genetics book by Monroe *Strickberger* (but I can't access it right now)

Comment: @Qwerty Thanks for your appreciation. glad to write something helpful